# MPI for python broadcast

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hi guys I am new here so please excuse me if I make any errors. I use python to write some code for my masters project and recently started using mpi4py to make my code parallel since I have available 12 cores and also for time purposes. I cannot for some reason get the bcast function to work. I want to work out `T2` in the root process then broadcast it to all the other processes. My code is as follows:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from qutip import*
from scipy import*
from pylab import*
from numpy import*

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

N0=10
N1=N0
N2=N0
d_ep=0.031
I_s=qeye(2)

if rank==0:
    T2=0
    for k in range (0,N1):
        n1=basis(N1+N2,k+N1)
        kk=k+1
        T2=T2+kk*(n1*n1.dag())
    T2=(d_ep/N1)*tensor(I_s,T2)
else:
    T2=0

comm.bcast(T2, root=0)

print T2,rank
```

But when I run this code the output I get looks like this:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
Quantum object: dims = [[2, 4], [2, 4]], shape = [8, 8], type = oper, isherm = True
Qobj data =
[[ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.0155  0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.031   0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.0155  0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.031 ]] 0
```

it did work out `T2` in the root but it didn't broadcast it to the others they are all `0`. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use:

```
T2 = comm.bcast(T2, root=0)
```

This is the correct usage of `bcast` according to the [mpi4py tutorial.](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html#collective-communication)

Comment: Hi thank you very much I have been at this for days! I will take a look at the link you posted. It's amazing the actual documentation that came with MPI with all the tutorials in it don't mention that your variable must equal the bcast function they just write the bcast function straight.